# How do I obtain the Android context in BeanShell for SL4A?

Tags: android, android-context, sl4a, beanshell

I started exploring BeanShell for [SL4A](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/) because I [read](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/FAQ#Is_this_a_complete_API_bridge,_or_are_there_restrictions?) that it could access the entire Android API. This would facilitate experimenting with API features and programming ideas without the need for a computer or compilation.

However, much of the API is accessed through a `Context`, and I don't know how to obtain this. Although both SL4A and BeanShell are well-documented, the combination of the two seems to be very poorly documented.

For example, to access [`android.net.ConnectivityManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html), the developer reference states that I need to call `Context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE)` to get an instance. But without a context, I don't think I'm able to access the methods of the `ConnectivityManager`.

So how do I obtain the `Context`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dahrrr…

While researching and formulating the question, I found out that this [is an unresolved issue](https://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/wiki/Unofficial#Notes_for_Java_interpreters):

> **Notes for Java interpreters**
>
> Beanshell and Rhino can both directly access the android api. However, many Android api calls required a context, which, due to the way they are run, these interpreters don't have. A solution is being sought... suggestions appreciated.

Comment: As it's apparently not yet possible, I have now [raised an issue on their tracker](http://code.google.com/p/android-scripting/issues/detail?id=704).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know sl4a or beanshell but i know Rhino. So i suppose that you can create scriptable objects too. If this is correct you can do something like this (in java):

```
// first create a simple scope called -> scope


// inject context.
 Object injectObject = Context.javaToJS(android_context, scope);    // ('Context' of rhino library)
 ScriptableObject.putProperty(scope, "android_context_name", injectObject);

// so then execute your script with the injected object
 execute(javascript_context, host, scope, scriptId, source, settings);
```

---

When you finish injected the the context you can access him via: "android_context_name". (inside your script).

Comment: I don't really know BeanShell either; I understand it to be interpreted Java, which of the available SL4A options, seemed like it would be the best way to access the API without writing an application. And any code I write while experimenting should be transferable to give me a head start if I decide to make an application out of it. I've looked at your answer a few times. Rhino is one of the interpreters available for SL4A, but you say you're not using SL4A, so how are you using Rhino?

Comment: I don't understand your code or how to translate it into a solution in BeanShell for SL4A. It looks like a combination of JavaScript and Java – two languages that I'm not fond of, or particularly fluent in. I would be much happier if the SL4A Python interpreter had access to the API rather than the watered-down ‘façade’ scheme of SL4A, or even better if it had a Haskell interpreter! But it doesn't, so I'd like to keep to Java because it is the primary language for Android development; It's much easier to relate the API documentation to Java code. Could you give me any hints on how to progress?

Comment: Well, i don't know why you need exactly BeanShell. But the tip that i can give you is try to inject 'Android Context' in script. In the example above i explain a way to do in rhino.. so if you can find a way using SL4A documentation to inject context in whatever script (doesn't matter the language) then you can be able to acces it via a name that you give when inject the context in the script. I'll edit some things in the example to be more explicit

Comment: sorry man forget what i said before. Maybe exist a hack to do that or simple way. I'm read some articles and nothing.. so if you find a way post it :D.... you dont try with droid = android.Android()... to get droid.getContext() or something like that?

Answer (score -1):

When you run your bean shell script, it will be thru an android app ?

There are such available

e.g : BeanShell Executor, that will allow you to run a script.

So I assume the context  will be passed from the app to the script being executed.

Comment: You should not say that **I assume**. You should be clear in your answer.

Comment: Check out http://www.androidguys.com/2008/08/06/scripting-your-android-device/, which has an example of using context in BeanShell